# How do I put custom image on 3D Sphere in ARCore

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

The following is my code for building a 3D Earth and showing it:

```
com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Texture.Builder builder= com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Texture.builder();
builder.setSource(context,R.drawable.earth);
builder.build().thenAccept(texture ->
        MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithTexture(context, texture).
                thenAccept(material -> {
                  earthSphereRenderable =
                          ShapeFactory.makeSphere(0.1f, new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), material);
                  Toast.makeText(context,"All done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();})
);
```

The Toast message is coming but I am not able to see any object. Please note that R.drawable.earth is the Earth.jpg file that I put in there, which I want to show in AR.

Here is where I am rendering it

```
cornerNode = new Node();
    cornerNode.setParent(this);
    cornerNode.setLocalPosition(localPosition);
    cornerNode.setRenderable(earthSphereRenderable);
```

Moreover, if I replace makeOpaqueWithTexture with makeOpaqueWithColor and but color as Red then the whole thing is working fine (i.e. I can see the sphere)

What must I change here in order to be able to see the sphere with Earth's texture on it?

Comment: Can you try to move the jpg to raw ?  I think the  texture builder only works with raw resources (or assets).

Comment: Where do I put the raw image then? I cannot place it in the drawable folder. Moreover, I don't think there is a way to convert jpg to raw (there is a way to do the opposite though)

Comment: you can make a directory in the res directory named "raw" and place the jpg in there.  There is no need to convert the format.  You can then reference it in the code as R.raw.earth.  The raw folder stores the files as-is, whereas drawable resources are bundled together and can have different content based on the screen density.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer to this. It does not accept jpg files but it accepts png files. Weird stuff!

Answer (score 1):

At this time `Google Sceneform 1.8` supports 3D assets in the following formats: **`.obj`**, **`.glTF`** for which animations not supported) and **`.fbx`** with or without animations. Supported textures' formats are: `.mtl`, `.bin`, `.png` and `.jpg`.

## To import a new **3D asset with textures** follow these steps:

Verify that your project's app folder contains a sampledata folder. To create the folder, right-click on the app folder in the Project window, then select `New` > `Sample Data Directory`.

The sampledata folder is part of your Android Studio project, but its contents will not be included in your APK. Copy your 3D model source asset file (`.obj`, `.fbx`, or `.gltf`), and all of its dependencies in any of the following formats:

- `.mtl`
- `.bin`
- `.png`
- `.jpg`

into the sampledata folder.

> Do not copy these source files into your project's assets or `res` folder, as this will cause them to be included in your APK unnecessarily. Right click the 3D model source asset and select ***`Import Sceneform Asset`*** to begin the import process.

The values are used by the `sceneform.asset()` entry in the app's **`build.gradle`**, and determine where the `.sfa` and `.sfb` – ascii and binary asset definition – files (as well as their corresponding texture files `.sfm`) will be generated in your project. If you're importing a model for the first time, use the default values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is when you want to load a model designed with some modeler CAD software. He is using the `MaterialFactory` to create everything programmatically.